# SDL_AudioStreamFlush could not be located in the dynamic link library SDL2_mixer.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdl, sdl-mixer

I'm just trying to follow along with the c++ graphics tutorial from MakingGamesWithBen about SDL mixer, an audio system.  I got the development library from:
[SDL_Mixer Development Library Download](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/).

It's the SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.2-VC.zip folder under development libraries for Visual C++.  I've done all the same steps as what he is showing, though I've been using x64 instead of x86.  When I try running the project though, it gives me the error
"SDL_AudioStreamFlush could not be located in the dynamic link library [file path] SDL2_mixer.dll".  I'm not using the function SDL_AudioStreamFlush in my code at all, which is what perplexes me about this.  I honestly don't have any clue how to fix this, and online documentation doesn't seem to help.  Any assistance would be much appreciated, because I have tried looking on sites for other similar questions, but nothing I can use.  Below should be a dropbox link to my entire solution.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0blrourluyjpsca/AACs4bHdZs83q_R8lSjFINIEa?dl=0

Comment: SDL audio streams were added in SDL 2.0.6. It appears you use older version, while your version of SDL2_mixer already depends on it.

Comment: Oh okay, so either I need to update my version of SDL or use an older version of SDL2_mixer.  That actually makes sense.  I will try that tonight and see if it works.

Comment: That worked instantly.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when using `SDL_mixer` and `SDL_ttf`.

When  I change the old `SDL2.dll` in my folder (I put them all: header files, library files, and binary files in one directory) with the newest one (the one that is in the lib/X86/SDL2.dll) it works.